# html - вопрос про подменю

Tags: html, css

У меня проблема с кодами в субменю. Субменю работает некорректно и не подключается ко второму меню кнопки. Смотрите на фото и на коды:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**html:**

```
    <nav class="bottomMenu">
<ul id="dropdown_nav">

<li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Bosh Sahifa</a></li>
<li><a href="instituthaqida.html">Institut haqida</a></li>
<ul class="sub_nav">
                <li><a href="#">Подменю #1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Подменю #2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Подменю #3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Подменю #4</a></li>
            </ul>
<li><a href="fakultetlar.html">Fakultetlar</a></li>
<li><a href="talabalaruchun.html">Talabalar uchun</a></li>

    </ul>
       **</nav><!-- конец #bottomMenu -->**
```

**CSS - Выпадающее меню:**

```
#dropdown_nav .sub_nav {
                        z-index: 4;
            width:180px;
            padding:0px;
            position:absolute;
            top:42px;
            left:0px;
            border:0px solid #ddd;
            border-top:none;
            background: #000;
                       }

            #dropdown_nav .sub_nav li {

            width:180px;
            padding:0px;
            }

            #dropdown_nav .sub_nav li a {
             background: none;
             font-weight: normal;
             font-size:15px;
             display:block;
             border-bottom:0px solid #e5e0b3;
             padding-left:10px;
             color:#fff;

            }
            #dropdown_nav .sub_nav li a:hover {
            background:#222;
            color:#0dbfe5;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что детьми `<ul></ul>` могут быть только `<li></li>` элементы, а у Вас `<ul>` содержит другой `<ul>`. Правильный вариант - заключить (`<ul class="sub_nav">`) в пункт меню родительского списка.

```
<nav class="bottomMenu">
      <ul id="dropdown_nav">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Bosh Sahifa</a></li>
        <li><a href="instituthaqida.html">Institut haqida</a>
          <ul class="sub_nav">
            <li><a href="#">Подменю #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подменю #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подменю #3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подменю #4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="fakultetlar.html">Fakultetlar</a></li>
        <li><a href="talabalaruchun.html">Talabalar uchun</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ)))))))